# Socket.IO Invalid frame header after http Reqest

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a nodejs express Rest API and I want to add websocket support.
I'm using [this](https://github.com/w3tecch/express-typescript-boilerplate) boilerplate for the api part and added [this](https://github.com/typestack/socket-controllers) library and socket.io to use websockets in the same project (I'm not sure if it matters).

My websockets work as expected without the Rest API but as soon as I make an http request to my API, connections to the websocket fail with the following error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Invalid frame header

Already established connections still work though.
This problem remains until I restart my server.

I found a lot of different possible causes for this error but none of which really helped me.

Edit:
This is how I connect to the websockets.

```
const rooms = io.connect(
    'http://localhost:3000/rooms',
    { transports: ['websocket'] }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by switching my stack to nestjs.
The problem was probably because both websocket and rest api were running on the same port